# SSIS - dynamic rows

Tags: dynamic, ssis, rows

I'm working with SSIS and I have a requisite that include creating a n number of rows.

I have a database to store data in a table as a name value pair.

Considering two files, one for customers and one for accounts

customer file example: (john, aCity, aId)
account file example: (anAccount, aNumberAccount, anAmount)

I want to store this data in the name value pair table like:

(customer, name, john)
(customer, address, aCity)
(customer, id, aId)
(account, name, anAccount)
(account, nrAccount, aNumberAccount)
(account, amount, anAmount)

I want to this without define two different flows for each type of file.

First question: Is this even possible?

Second question: If it's possible, how could I manage to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same transformation service?" How does the data in `file 1` map to the data in `file 2` What's dynamic about this?

Comment: using a script component to split each line of the file and saved the values on a table. 
this table is like a name value pair so I can save the data as column name column value

use this example I can put the data as userName:name1, carLicence:carLicence1 in the same table

Comment: Still not quite getting what your process looks like. Could you edit the question showing sample source data, how it should be brought together (if needed) and how it should look in the end?

Answer (score -1):

No... please make sure you have some simmilarity between bothh file and read it and add the merge task to merge both file